# uploading reads to ENA using aspera

Tags: database

Once again, I am trying to upload reads to ENA using aspera. Following their instructions I used several times in past (successfully) to upload my reads

```
ascp -QT -l300M -L- *.fastq.gz Webin-XXXXX@webin.ebi.ac.uk:.
```

it starts as usual, uploads by the ~300M/s speed. But when it gets to ~30 - 40% complete transfer, it gets aborted from the server site:

```
RR PEER ABORT: Received sesserr notification from peer, reason FASP_ABORT_LOCAL
ERR PEER ABORTED: Shutting down source/transmitter, reason FASP_ABORT_LOCAL
ERR Cannot write to management socket localhost:35666, Connection reset by peer (server)
LOG Sender bl t/o/r/dl/c/h=2672819/2672819/0/0/2668562/2668562 ctl bm/bs=0/0 rex b/r/n=0/0/0 r_ott q/s/n=0/0/1001 rate t/m/c=300000000/0/300000000 prog t/f/e=3762237952/376223795
2/104125014 xmtD=0
LOG Sender DS Qs ds/re/a/d/ao/eo/n/ap/rq/rd/ru/cl/di/do=1/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/0/0/0 Rs o/i=1/1 mgmt backlog i/s/n =
LOG Sender bl t/o/r/dl/c/h=2672946/2672946/0/0/2668562/2668562 ctl bm/bs=0/0 rex b/r/n=0/0/0 r_ott q/s/n=0/0/1001 rate t/m/c=300000000/0/300000000 prog t/f/e=3762237952/376223795
2/104125014 xmtD=0
LOG Sender DS Qs ds/re/a/d/ao/eo/n/ap/rq/rd/ru/cl/di/do=1/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0/1/0/0/0 Rs o/i=1/1 mgmt backlog i/s/n =
ERR FASP sender had error, errcode 19 errstr [Cannot write to management socket localhost:35666, Connection reset by peer (server)]
ERR Peer FASP receiver had error, errcode 74 errstr [Cannot write to management socket localhost:35666, Connection reset by peer]
ERR Cannot write to management socket localhost:35666, Connection reset by peer (server), Cannot write to management socket localhost:35666, Connection reset by peer
              
Session Stop  (Error: Cannot write to management socket localhost:35666, Connection reset by peer (server), Cannot write to management socket localhost:35666, Connection reset by
 peer)
```

Does anyone have an idea what went wrong?

I also asked ENA helpdesk, if I will get an answer from them I will forward it here.

Comment: have you tried with a lower value for `-l`? Maybe `-l200M`

Comment: I tried -l100M and it failed around 15%, so I tried also 1500M and our bandwidth actually managed to transfer nearly 900M/s and although it dropped some of the same errors, it also said that the file transfer was successful. Might be a workaround, it's certainly not a scalable solution